# SharePoint 2007 Search Webservice client call - darrenjohn's API

Tags: 2007, web-services, javascript, client-object-model, development

I want to get the same result set as sharepoint search returns using webservice/object model, what is right way of doing it?

Let's say:
If sharepoint search core result webpart says 20 items/result found against given search keyword, my custom code should also return the same result set (20 items).

I have tried with the darren john's SPAPI(keyward search, fulltext search) however it does not return the results as sharepoint searchcore webpart returns.

Please help me, i'm looking for the solution since quite a long time.

Otherwise, do you think it is easy to write our own custom search core webpart, if so, any reference.

Comment: What are all the properties used for Searching ? is it all the metadata properties will be used for the default search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of SPAPI, have you tried SPServices:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

It is well documented and includes the search Web services:

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Search&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices

Comment: I want to sort the Search Core Result Webpart results based on the selected custom property, I know, it is not directly possible to implement however do you have alternative way of doing it? otherwise, if i want to have a custom webpart, do you have reference link?